# IDOC not trigger from SAP but able to see in BizTalk

Tags: biztalk

In am working on some integration scenario where BizTalk is used as middle-ware just for pass-through. SAP RFC is the source connectivity & target is AS2 server. I am encountering a situation where the AS2 server is receiving extra IDOC's from BizTalk. I can see in BizTalk that IDOC is received. I can confirm this by checking -

1. BAM
2. Checking port initiation though tracked message events.

When checked in SAP it seems the extra IDOC was not even triggered from SAP. Please suggest something, I am not having any idea on this issue.

Comment: Hi Sunil.  Did my answer below help you solve your problem?  If yes, you should give it a green tick.  If not, please update your question with what you've checked and discarded.  Also you should look at the context properties of the messages to see where they originated from.

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving one document, but sending two, then the issue will most likely be a subscription issue in some ports.

For example, if you have a Send Port Group that has the same filter that a Send Port that is bound to it.  Then both will subscribe to and send the same message, so you end up with two.

The other scenario is that you have both an Orchestration that receives from the Receive port and sends a message to the send port and the Send port has a subscription that directly listens for those messages that come from the Receive Port.